# Why do I get this error (Cannot read from the source file or disk)

Tags: document-library, error, explorer-view

Why do I get this error (Cannot read from the source file or disk) when trying to move a folder and its files from a document library on one My Site to desktop

Comment: Hi - this site is designed primarily for the administrators of such systems. I would suggest that, if you are not the administrator that you contact them and let them deal with the issue. If you are the administrator, please provide more information, such as your Sharepoint version (And maybe screenshots) so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with the timing of how Windows treats a file 'Move'. Unfortunately it's incompatible with the way SharePoint works, so all you can do is to 'copy' the file to your desktop, then delete the file from your MySite afterwards.